# .Net Reflector Red and green squares

Tags: disassembly, .net-reflector

What are the green and red squares? Are these variable names and strings being obfuscated purposely? Is there a 'deobfuscator'?

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

At a glance I would say it's unicode characters which don't have a printable representation

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is probably the result of an obfuscator. The characters are appearing as boxes because the font you are using in Reflector does not have a glyph for the character being shown.

I think [Dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator.html) does this type of obfuscation. You can check by looking at the attributes of the assembly for a `Dotfuscator` attribute.

Comment: What really? im pretty sure they're just english character since the ddls i'm disassembling are from an english speaking company.

Comment: Some obfuscators can obfuscate strings within the assembly. I know Dotfuscator can do this.